# Is it possible to import resorce file into visual studio if I have only Localization.fr.resx

Tags: visual-studio

And I don't have without Localization.fr.designer.cs file? Maybe visual studio can generate it automatically for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you can import it to visual studio. and restore the file.

1.From the menu bar choose Tools, Options.
2.On the Options dialog box, navigate to Source Control, Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.
3.Select Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer, and then choose OK.
4.From the menu bar choose View, Other Windows, Source Control Explorer.
5.In Source Control Explorer, navigate to the folder that contains the item you want to restore.
6.Open the item’s shortcut menu and then choose Undelete.

Comment: Try this below commadn:                                          resgen [parameters] [/compile]filename.extension [outputFilename.extension] [/str:lang[,namespace[,class[,file]]]]